# arranging matrix - network graphs

Tags: r, graph, matrix, sna

I was trying to make a network graph, using the function `gplot` from `library(sna)`. The graph would represent the links between different fields.
I have the following data:

```
MTM <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
FI <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
MCLI <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
mat1 <- data.frame(MTM,FI,MCLI)
mat1 <- as.matrix(mat1)
```

Where "MTM", "FI" and "MCLI" are the "fields of interest" and every row is a different project that has some/any/none of the fields in common. 
How could I transform these data to look like this?

```
matx:   
       MTM   FI   MCLI
MTM     10    0   1
FI       0    1   1
MCLI    10    1   17
```

I am interested in representing -in a network graph- the fields as "nodes", and the connections as "edges". This could be helpful in representing the most "popular" and interconnected fields. Is it possible with these data?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894190/basic-sna-in-r-how-to-load-network-data) solution, which could be OK for what I want:

```
library(igraph)
G<-graph.incidence(as.matrix(mat1),weighted=TRUE,directed=FALSE)
summary(G)
plot(G)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to make a network graph from your data where each node is a "field of interest". Note that I have made a symmetrical adjacency matrix from your original data that doesn't entirely match your desired matrix output.

```
library(igraph)

# Use matrix multiplication to create symmetrical adjacency matrix.
adj_mat = t(mat1) %*% (mat1)

# Two ways to show edge weights.
png("igraphs.png", width=10, height=5, units="in", res=200)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

g1 = graph.adjacency(adj_mat, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE, weighted=TRUE)
plot(g1, edge.width=E(g1)$weight, vertex.size=50)

g2 = graph.adjacency(adj_mat, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
plot(g2, vertex.size=50)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: wow! Thanks, I will take good note of this code, specially the matrix operation to create the adjacency_matrix. So much to learn. Although it doesn't match my initial thoughts, both graphs reflect exactly my idea. The meaning of that "fields of interest" acronyms (not sure if well expressed) are in english: Clinical Medicine, Math, and Physics.